# Catch specific sub-exception

Tags: python, exception

I have some code which parses what may or may not be a valid JSON string. I want to catch this exception in the `except` clause:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 1 - line 1 column 19 (char 1 - 19)
```

But not this exception:

```
ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 1 column 3 (char 3)
```

Would I code it as a variant of this:

```
try:
    json.loads(user_sting)
except ValueError as e:
    # How to parse 'e' now?
    handle_error(e)
```

Or as a variant of this:

```
try:
    json.loads(user_sting)
except ValueError['Extra data'] as e:
    handle_error(e)
```

The difference that I am making is on the "Extra data" or "Expecting" string between the two `:` characters. I do suppose that I could use the first method with a regex to parse `str(e)`, but if there is a more straightforward method then I would like to know. Being Python, I suspect that there is!

Comment: What is `ValueError['Extra data']` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.args` instead of `str(e)`:

```
try:
    json.loads('""extra-data')
except ValueError as e:
    if e.args[0].startswith('Extra data:'):
        handle_error(e)
    else:
        raise
```

IMHO, there's no syntax sugar like `except ValueError['Extra data'] ..`.

Comment: Thank you, this exactly answers my suspicions. Thanks for teh codez, too!